# How to turn off the MathJax preview?

Tags: support, faq, user-interface, mathjax

The constant compiling of MathJax while composing a post is undesirable for me. How can I stop the MathJax preview?

Is there a way to turn off the MathJax preview?

Where is the button to switch off MathJax while typing a post?

Comment: This may bot be that much of an issue on this site, but as I had written this for MO I thought I could just as well repost it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official feature for this. However, it is possible to get this functionality using bookmarklets (for further details see below).

The following code was posted by [Jack Schmidt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/583/jack-schmidt) on [meta.math.se](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2581):

> To pause it:
>
> ```
> javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=1;})();
> ```
>
> To turn it back on:
>
> ```
> javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=0;})();
> ```

### How to use this?

Preparation:

- Create two bookmarks or favorites (or whatever your browser calls the functionality to save the address of some website), call them for example "MathJax: Off" and "MathJax: On".
- Copy the line of code `javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=1;})();` in the field where one usually puts the URL for the bookmark "MathJax: Off" Do the same with `javascript:(function(){MathJax.Hub.queue.pending=0;})();` for "MathJax: On"

Usage:

- When you want to stop MathJax, bring up your bookmark list (if you do not show it by default) and click "MathJax: Off"
- When you want to restart MathJax do the same for "MathJax: On" Note that rendering might not start instantly. Possibly add some more characters to the post to get it started.